# Microsoft edge legacy extension icon got disabled just after updating extension

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Microsoft edge legacy extension toolbar icon got disabled after updating extension version and we can not open extension popup, if we do any activity just after updating extension.

Microsoft edge legacy disabled extension toolbar icon got re-enable after 15-20 minutes and we can open extension popup. we are calling server API calls on extension update and sync data with local storage. we are not sure that is bug of edge or our code.

Answer (score 0):

> we are calling server API calls on extension update and sync data
>   with local storage.

Whether this part of code will change the extension icon? whether you set the Sync Interval (describes how often synchronization occurs)? If you are using it to change the extension icon, it might have some delay.

I have tested the [official extension sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/creating-an-extension) on my side, it seems that the extension icon will change immediately when I upload the new edge extension.

Try to reload your extension: click the... for settings and more in Microsoft Edge, click Extensions, click on your extension, and click Reload extension. And, you could also try to clear the browsing data and restart the Edge Browser.